# Python 2.7: how I can get value from the subclass

Tags: python, subclass

```
class MyWindow():

    class Filter(QtCore.QObject):

        def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
            # FocusOut event            
            if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut:
                # do custom stuff
                print('Focus Event')
                isFocusEvent = True
                return False
            else:
                # we don't care about other events
                return False                

            return isFocusEvent

    def __init__(self, ui):
        self.ui=ui

    def mycode (self)
        myvalue=float(self.ui.myvalueEdit.text()) 

        self._filter = self.Filter()
        self.ui.myvalueEdit.installEventFilter(self._filter)

        if (isFocusEvent == True):
            ..........
            ..........
```

Hi, I use a Qt interface with python 2.7, I'd get the focusOutEvent (only from one Qt's field) and then save all the self.ui.xxxx values. 
I am not able to get the "isFocuEvent" test!! There is not problem for the saving procedure.
Could you help me please?
Thank you!

Comment: I'm confused, why not just change `eventFilter` to return `event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut`. That will tell you if it's a focus event or not.

Comment: `isFocusEvent = True` only sets it to a **local variable** the only way to make it accessible is to keep a lasting reference to it, like a global or an attribute of the `Filter` instance, so you could do `self.isFocusEvent = True` and then below when you want to check it use `if self._filter.isFocusEvent`

Comment: Thank you, I modified it with the self prefix (such as your first suggestion) and returned the value with retur self.isFocusEvent but in Mywindow class I recive the following error: "print self._filter.isFocusEvent()           
AttributeError: 'Filter' object has no attribute 'isFocusEvent'

Comment: In the second case it returns the "None" value. I used the return event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.FocusOut (instead of the previous code)and in the Mywindow() I used: print(self.ui.LFcutoffEdit.installEventFilter(self._filter))